# how to run mongodb native (not json) query in spring-data-mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I want to execute the below native query in spring data mongodb:

```
var arrayConta = [];
var arrayPan = [];
db.cardaccount.find({"migrationResult.status" :"MIGRADO"}).forEach(function(doc) {
    arrayConta.push({
        "updateMany": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "processorId": doc.processorId.substr(0,9)+"XXXXXX"+doc.processorId.substr(15,4)} }
        }
    });

doc.plastics.forEach(function(pans){
    arrayPan.push({
        "updateMany": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "plastics.0.pan": pans.pan.substr(0,6)+"XXXXXX"+pans.pan.substr(12,4)} }
                      }

    });

    });

    if ( arrayConta.length === 50 ) {
        db.cardaccount.bulkWrite(arrayConta);
        db.cardaccount.bulkWrite(arrayPan);
        arrayConta = [];
        arrayPan = [];
    }

})

if ( arrayConta.length > 0 ) {
    db.cardaccount.bulkWrite(arrayConta);
    db.cardaccount.bulkWrite(arrayPan);
    arrayConta = [];
    arrayPan = [];
}
```

I tried with @Query don't work.I received the error below.

> `readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.`

Then I try with mongoOperation.executeCommand(comandString), too don't work. How can I make it work?
Please help...

Regards

db.version() -> 4.0.4-15-g7ad4f64;
spring boot version: 2.3.2.RELEASE